# Does gmail avoid from some emails even to be in spam box?

Tags: gmail, email-bounces

Does gmail avoid from some emails even to be in spam box?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really much of a sysadmin question... rather a Google customer service question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gmail has strict e-mail policies and they do indeed reject a lot of e-mail before it even enters the system.

Especially if we are talking bulk e-mail such as newsletters and such. Google has a lot of advice listed here: https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126

Also they most likely (like most other large e-mail providers) have some internal rules that are not public, which can cause e-mail to be rejected.

Comment: thanks you very much, but in this link only says about spam emails and not emails that not even enters to system.please can you give me reference for that?

Comment: To get to know the reason for the e-mails being rejected by Google you will have to investigate the log files on the sending MTA. If you do not have access to these you should ask your host to look in the log files for you.